# C# Timer Callback to use returned value from a function every loop

Tags: c#, timer, callback

I want to achieve something that i don't know if its possible, but there goes nothing...

i have a static  int variable called X, and a function that increments X then returns the new value.

```
 public static int X;

 public int ReturnInt()
    {
        X = X + 1
        return x;
    }
```

i have another function which is a TimerCallBack function that will be looped over every N milliseconds.

```
public static void TimerCallback(Object o)
    {
        y = ReturnInt();
        Console.WriteLine("Value:" + y);
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

then in the main function:-

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Timer t = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, X * 1000);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This application only works on the first loop because it can only see the incremented value of X on the first loop of the Timer then remains constant without updating.

so the output is:

```
Value:1
```

what i want to do is use the Timer function's last parameter to multiply X's value (as it changes everytime the loop is over) with the milliseconds.

is this even possible?

Comment: @Sean T can you please explain how it should be done?

Comment: I've added an answer below, should be enough to get you on your way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you instantiate your Timer, what you are actually doing is to set both the `dueDate` and `period` to 0 (X is 0 at start time). The `dueDate` equals to 0 means that the timer starts immediately, and the `period` 0 means that there won't be any more repetitions. This is odd because in the documentation it says that you should specify `System.Threading.Timeout.Infine` to disable periodic signaling.

You can try something like this to change the time interval between the `TimerCallback` calls:

```
public static int X;
public static Timer timer;
public static int ReturnInt()
{
    X = X + 1;
    return X;
}

public static void TimerCallback(object o)
{
    var y = ReturnInt();
    Console.WriteLine("Value:" + y);
    timer.Change(y * 1000, 0);
    GC.Collect();
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 0);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

In `Main` you create a timer that runs immediately and, in the `TimerCallback` method you change the timers properties using the `timer.Change(y * 1000, 0)`, and so the method will be called at y * 1000 milliseconds each time the value changes.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

How about declare x outside the main body, pass it through as an aboject to the callback.

```
public Int x = 0;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Timer t = new Timer(TimerCallback, x, 0, x * 1000);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

pass it in to the incremental method.

```
private int ReturnInt(int x)
{
    x = x + 1
    return x;
}
```

and in your callback you take it from the object you passed into it for the delegate?

```
private void TimerCallback(int x)
{
    var y = ReturnInt(x);
    Console.WriteLine("Value:" + y);
    GC.Collect();
}
```

You would need to set some condition when to stop this as `x` will get very large very quickly. This is just set to run indefinitley.

Comment: @MahmoudElbably Well, you've declared x as `private` for some reason. That's not what I posted

Comment: This is useful reference for scope and keywords in c# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

Comment: I changed it but it says : cannot convert  from 'method group' to 'TimerCallback'

Comment: `Timer t = new Timer(TimerCallback, x, 0, x * 1000);` <-- this line?

Comment: It's because there is already a methd called `TimerCallback` I think- change its name to something else

Comment: This is the only TimerCallback function i have in the code.

Comment: Maybe in your code yes, however c# has many other methods built in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timercallback?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: That error means it does not know what method from the two to use

Comment: @MahmoudElbably honestly mate, there's no need to downvote me just because you are unable to follow instructions, It's a valid answer.

Comment: i swear i didn't even vote your answer, that was someone else! i would never do that to someone helping me.. i don't even have the authority yet to vote on an answer so that i shows to the public

Comment: @MahmoudElbably ok my mistake, as I say I just trying to help. Good luck with getting it working. By all means downvote if the code it wrong but it does what you initially asked for :)